# is there a faster way to convert a column of pyspark dataframe into python list? (Collect() is very slow )

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to store a column of pyspark dataframe into python list using collect function.
e.g.

**list_a = [row[column_name] for row in dataset_name.collect()]**

but this is very slow process and takes more than 10 seconds for a dataframe of 3 columns and 27 rows.

is there a faster way to do so?

**I tried caching the data before this step** . With this step, the above query is being executed in 2 seconds but cache step itself is taking around 7-8 seconds so my purpose of reducing time is not full filled.

And my code is such that i need to rebuild the dataframe everytime before this step so need to do cache again so this step(caching the dataframe) is not helping a lot in time reduction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Your code can be slightly optimized by only collecting one column of data:

```py
list_a = [row[column_name] for row in dataset_name.select(column_name).collect()]
```

This code is cleaner if you use [quinn](https://github.com/MrPowers/quinn/):

```py
import quinn

list_a = quinn.column_to_list(df, col_name)
```

`collect()` transfers all the data to the driver node and is expensive.  You can only make it faster by collecting less data (e.g. `dataset_name.select(column_name).distinct().collect()` would typically be faster).

Spark is optimized for distributing datasets across a cluster and running computations in parallel.  The distributed nature of Spark makes computations that collect results on a single node comparatively slow.